# Create trigger to update total salary of the department as new employee is added

Tags: sql-server, triggers

```
create trigger t
on Employee 
for insert
as
    update Department
    set Department.Total_Salary = Department.Total_Salary + NEW.Salary
    where Department.Dno = NEW.Dno
```

but this generates an error

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure t, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 25]
>   The multi-part identifier "NEW.Dno" could not be bound.

What is the cause?

Comment: There is no such thing as `NEW` in SQL Server - have you come from another DB background? I think you are looking for `inserted` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11871324/sql-server-trigger-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound

Comment: I would like to observe that using a trigger like this to update a total in another table is very likely to cause issues with your data moving forwards (what happens on updates, deletions, if an error occurs and the figure isn't updated or rolled back properly).  It would usually be recommended that the total salary for the department be calculated when retrieving the data (such as through a department view).  

The current form of the trigger will also only work if a single record is inserted, if multiple are inserted you won't have the desired outcome.

Comment: Unless you have specific performance concerns (and if you do, there are better ways to address them), don't *store* data that can be *calculated* from other data. All you do by storing the data is *introduce* the possibility that the stored calculated data and the base data become out of sync.